Unable to convert an infinite addition to a function
I am aiming to make a function, $f(n)$, that doesn't include infinite addition like this :
$1+2+3+\cdots+(n^2+2n-1)$
but a function like this (for example) :
$\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{4x-3}{6x^2-51x+1}$
For making the formula looks smaller, let's consider :
$\displaystyle g(n) = 2^{\frac{2^{(n-1)}-1}{2^{(n-1)}}}$
And then the desired function is :
$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{g(x-1)+\sqrt{g(x-2)+\cdots\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}}}{g(x)}$
Can anyone help me ? Thanks .

It's not quite clear how you've got the $\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}$ in your definition of $f$. $g(1)=1$ and $g(2)=\sqrt2$ so are those two terms the wrong way round? It might be useful (both for the question and yourself) if you could write down the values of $f(n)$ for some small $n$.

If I've interpreted your notation correctly, you might find it easier to find a relationship between $f(n)$ and $f(n-1)$. If you multiply up and square both sides, you should be able to do this. Also, you can check that this process also does something nice to the $g$ terms; you can get a very succinct recurrence. Not only that, but there is a very neat way to write down $f(n)$; I'd suggest finding something out about the values of $f(n)$, making a conjecture and then trying to prove it. (Hint: arccos)

I don't understand any of this.  You say you want to avoid "infinite addition" but the only sums I see are finite anyway.

@ChrisLewis look, I got $f(x+1)=\sqrt{\frac{1+f(x)}{2}}$

@hasandarwish So already that's (hopefully) looking nicer to deal with. You might already know a sequence (or function) that looks a bit like that, but if not try the other hint I gave you.

@Randall The examples suggest that OP wants to eliminate any use of an ellipsis (i.e., "$\ldots$").
